# How to enable compression in hapi.js?

Tags: compression, gzip, hapi.js

I need to Enable "gzip" compression on the Hapi.js API endpoints to improve the performance on API data downtime and download data size.
**How should I enable compression in hapi.js ?**

Any idea pls...

Answer (score 4):

gzip is enabled by default, so look no further, inspect your headers